# issue: Router.use requires a middleware function but got a obj

Tags: node.js, express

i have looked at all the other solutions around and I still cant seem to fix it
here is my file structure and my home.js where I have my routing which I moved from my routes.js file
i have already tried adding module.exports = router to the bottom of my .js files [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQDbu.png)

Comment: Please don't post images, instead [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65270353/edit) your question and add the code for both the router and how you use it in your `index.js`. You might want to read this also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must register your router in app.js

[More about routes](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

```
const homeRouter = require('./web/home');

app.use('/home', homeRouter );
```